# Show secondary categories in layered navigation

Tags: magento2

I have products that sits in multiple categories.

Category structure looks like this:

```
Root
- Car Types
    |- SUV
    |- Crossover
    |- Coupe
- Volvo
- Volkswagen
```

The product is assigned to **SUV** and **Volvo**.

When you are in Volvo category, I want to show the category filter for SUV, Crossover, Coupe in the layered navigation. But right now it only shows the attributes. Not the other categories a product is assigned to.

So I can essentially click in the filter for "SUV" when I am in the "Volvo" category.

But then you say "use attributes". No. I want to have content on every category page, with custom CMS blocks and category texts and images. Attribute filter does not support this, and is not indexable by Google because of canonical urls etc.

Out of the box it does not seem that you can cross link like this.

Is this possible?

tl;dr

Show secondary categories for products in filtered navigation no matter what category you are browsing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , Your requirement is possible. You can check the below link for solution if that helps.

https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Programming/How-to-display-category-filter-on-layered-navigation-in-Magento/td-p/113933

Comment: You can try this extension too https://amasty.com/improved-layered-navigation.html